# Is there some notion of "Uniformly Discontinuous" function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose there is a function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (I is some non-empty interval of real numbers) which is discontinuous everywhere. This means that for any $x \in I, \exists \epsilon_{x}> 0$ such that for any $\delta >0, \exists x_{\delta} \in I$ such that $|x-x_{\delta}|< \delta $, but $|f(x) - f(x_{\delta})| \geq \epsilon_x$.

I was wondering whether there would always exist a uniform such $\epsilon$, i.e., an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $x \in I$, and for any $\delta >0$, $\exists x_{\delta} \in I$ such that $|x-x_{\delta}|< \delta $, but $|f(x) - f(x_{\delta})| \geq \epsilon$.

For example, if $f$ was the Dirichlet function (1 on rationals, 0 on irrationals), then $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ would work.

This gave me the feel of "Uniform Continuity", as in that case, for every  $\epsilon > 0$, we have a uniform $\delta_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that for any $x ,y\in I$ with $|x-y|<\delta_{\epsilon}$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, whereas in the proposed sense of "Uniform Discontinuity", we would have a uniform $\epsilon>0$ such that no $x\in I$ has a corresponding $\delta$.

Does such a "uniform $\epsilon$" always exist for an everywhere discontinuous function $f$ on I? In other words, is each everywhere discontinuous function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ necessarily "Uniformly Discontinuous"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=1$, $f(r)=r$ for rational $r$ and otherwise $f(x)=0$ (for irrational $x$).  This is discontinuous everywhere but its oscillation at a positive $x$ becomes smaller and smaller as $x$ tends to zero, while at $x=0$ the oscillation is $1$.  Therefore there is no uniform lower bound.

Comment: Is there some developed theory on functions which are "Uniformly Discontinuous" ?